# Symfony2 on php 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.4

I need to change my Symfony2 website  to a new server and I've noticed that the new server is currently installed php 5.4, when Symfony2 need a minimum of 5.5.9. By doing some tests they are taking place some errors like:

> php.CRITICAL: Fatal Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'class'
>   (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
>   {"type":4,"file":"/home/admin/web/websitename.com/app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php","line":62,"level":6143,"stack":[]}
>   []

which is probably product of the version. I wonder if anyone has had this problem and has installed a Symfony2 in php 5.4, maybe down to an older version of the framework. I know that the easy way it would be to update the version of php but currently that's not an option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its actually Symfony3 that uses 5.5.9, Symfony2.8 still uses 5.3.9.

Comment: after composer install you should get messages about incompatibility

Comment: I just upload the source code, installation was in localhost with a 5.5.11 version.

Comment: blimey, find a new server!

Comment: @DevDonkey preferably a dedicated or virtual private server :P

Comment: @Flosculus apparently symfony 2.8 was not the problem, instead Doctrine  use the function ::class that appears after php 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem seems to be in doctrine common bundle I try with some old version of it, looking for some one compatible with php 5.4, specifically someone when the function`::class` is not used. Finally it work with the next combination:

```
"doctrine/common": "2.4.2",
"doctrine/dbal": "2.4.4",
"doctrine/orm": "2.4.7",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2"
```

Update composer and done.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a Symfony2 project to another server which have a different version of php (especially when it's a lower version) causes recurrently an error like yours.

Try to remove your `vendor` directory, maybe backup your `composer.lock` and redo a fresh installation by running `composer install` .

Also, manually remove all in the cache directory and verify the permissions of your server directories are the first things to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the real problem was the php version and doctrine, in a few minutes I going to publish the solution.